# How to sign and package a Xamarin.Forms application for IOS

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, publish, xamarin-studio

I have already signed, packaged and published my Xamarin.Forms application for Android. Now I want to do the same things for iOS also. What do I have to do these?
Note: I will use a Mac and will install the Xamarin Studio and Xcode applications, but don't know the rest, yet.

Answer (score 1):

IPA Support:

> This article covers how to create an IPA file that can be used to deploy an application using Ad Hoc distribution, either for testing, or for In-House distribution of internal applications.

[image]

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/ipa_support/